# Django Template: how to dump object on page in full

Tags: python, django, django-templates

The following template is not outputting anything despite there being data.

My question is... is there I was I can dump out into the template the content of 'points' object just so I can see what is in it?

template.py

```
 <h3>{% trans "Points" %}</h3>

    {% if points %}
        <p>{% trans "Total Points" %}: {{ points.Points }}</p>


        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>{% trans "Transaction" %}</th>
                <th>{% trans "Status" %}</th>
                <th>{% trans "Points" %}</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for item in points.Points_items.all %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ item.transaction_description }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.get_status_display }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.points }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stick this at the top:

```
<h1>|{{ points }}|</h1>
```

If there's nothing between the `|` then it's empty.

Comment: i just get this [<Points: Points object>, <Points: Points object>]  does that mean its empty then?

Comment: Is that nothing? or something?  If you want it to itemize the contents of points create an `__str__` or `__unicode__` method.

Answer (score 9):

I use a custom tag for this:

```
# Custom tag for diagnostics
@register.simple_tag()
def debug_object_dump(var):
    return vars(var)
```

And

```
{% load extra_tags %}
...
{% for thing in things %}
  <pre>{% debug_object_dump thing %}</pre>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `{% debug %}`, it dumps a lot of information, usefull to debug those situations.

More fine-grained there's also a `pprint` filter: `{{ points.Points|pprint }}`